# Gráfico de Área e Linha no R com Eixo x como String

Tags: r

Gostaria de realizar um gráfico de área e inserir um outro gráfico de linha sobreposto. Não estou conseguindo realizar isso, pois o gráfico do x que eu desejo colocar são strings e fica tudo errado. A figura deve ficar parecida com o gráfico abaixo que fiz em excel. Como vou ter que fazer vários em um loop, queria automatizar. Tentei usar o ggplot2 e o plotly, porém sem sucesso. O dataset pode ser adquirido através do link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwVpSqmgvCe-bFRsS0xxZmhQYnc/view?usp=sharing

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que o código abaixo resolve o teu problema.

```
library(ggplot2)

dados <- read.table(file="resposta.csv", header=T, sep=";")

ggplot(dados, aes(x=X, y=custo_med_gerFV_c_financ)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  geom_area(colour="blue", fill="blue") + 
  geom_line(aes(x=X, y=custo_med_rede), colour="darkorange", size=1.5) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=dados$X, labels=levels(dados$Disco)) + 
  labs(x="Concessionárias", y="Custo")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: é exatamente isso, porém a linha deveria estar em um segundo eixo. Tem como adaptar?

Comment: Como assim segundo eixo? Além da escala no eixo y e as cores, não percebo outra diferença entre o gráfico do Excel e o do ggplot2.

Comment: Não tem mesmo. O gráfico está perfeito. Porém em outros datasets eu terei que colocar outras variáveis no segundo eixo y que não apresentam a mesma escala da variável do primeiro eixo y. Sei que tem uma função do ggplot que faz isso, mas não estou conseguindo inserir no código que me enviou. O nome da função é sec_axis.